# How can I use order by and group by in Linq Extraction Method?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `person` list contains `person` has a `weight` and an `age` property.

`Person.cs`:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Weight { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

`Program.cs`:

```
List<Person> personList = new List<Person>();

personList.Add(new Person { Age = 15, Weight = 68 });
personList.Add(new Person { Age = 19, Weight = 75 });
personList.Add(new Person { Age = 17, Weight = 68 });
personList.Add(new Person { Age = 15, Weight = 55 });
personList.Add(new Person { Age = 15, Weight = 53 });
personList.Add(new Person { Age = 17, Weight = 88 });
personList.Add(new Person { Age = 19, Weight = 45 });
personList.Add(new Person { Age = 20, Weight = 88 });

//Grouped person list 
List<People> GroupedPersonList = new List<People>();

GroupedPersonList = personList.OrderBy(x => x.Weight).????
```

Elements that should be listed: Grouped by `age` and each group should be selected with the highest weight.(I want to order this list by `age`, but the list contains only the weightiest person of that age. Then I will create a new list via this.)
The new new list should look like this:

`(GroupedPersonList Contents)=>`

```
Age    | Weight 
-------|-------
15     | 68
17     | 88
19     | 75
20     | 88
```

How can I do that in LINQ extraction method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GroupBy` like this:

```
var GroupedPersonList = personList.GroupBy(x => x.Age , (key,element) => new
{
    Age = key,
    Weight = element.Max(c=>c.Weight)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

...or like

```
var groupedData = from person in people
                  orderby person.Age
                  group person by person.Age into ageGroup
                  select new { Age = ageGroup.Key, MaxWeight = ageGroup.Max(p => p.Weight) };

groupedData.ToList().ForEach(g =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", g.Age, g.MaxWeight);
});
```

Comment: Thank you,  have a nice day